# iOS Storyboard - Switch View to another view controller at same hierarchical level

Tags: ios, objective-c

If I have a storyboard that contains 3 views - a root, and two 'child' views that the root view can segue to. Is it possible for the children to segue to the other child, and then when its complete, return back to the root?

In my case, the root view may segue to view 'A' or 'B' depending on some event.  However, its possible that some event in 'A' may require view 'B' to be displayed, and when its done it should return back to root.  i.e., the steps of naviation would be:  Root -> ChildA -> ChildB -> Root.

Currently, I have the app setup to unwind from ChildA back to root, and have it then display 'B'.  Two issues arose from this method:

- Unable to segue to a new view when the unwind segue is still in operation.  I had to hack around this, and currently have a performSegueWithIdentifier being called with a small delay to get around it.  Obviously a bad hack.
- The root view controller is displayed for a moment until the new segue starts & completes.

I figured I could have A segue to B, but then when B was done, the unwind operation that I want to go back to root would have to unwind two items on the view stack??

I'm sure there has to be an obvious design choice that handles this type of thing right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I figured I could have A segue to B, but then when B was done, the unwind operation that I want to go back to root would have to unwind two items on the view stack??

Unwind operations are not required.  In your case, it might be better to have A segue to B, and when B is done, segue to root.  No unwind required.

If, however, you want to stick with unwinding, [Craig Phares posts how to perform multiple unwind animations without showing intermediate controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26788177/1114876) (i.e. you would pop right back to root).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  I'm using a root view controller that is a Navigation Controller to be able to utilize the built int 'back' behaviour in children view controllers.  If I simple segue back to the root from B, will I end up with a navigation stack that looks like 'Root->A->B->Root, with the '<Back' button available?  (Sorry, still new with iOS - I'm the in house android developer, and have had this iOS app dumped onto my plate so am trying to rapidly learn it as I go)

Comment: Ah, I see - you're using the built-in back button functionality of a `UINavigationController`.  In that case, you'll want to call [popToViewController:animated or popToRootViewController:animated:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UINavigationController/popToViewController:animated:) to get back to Root and keep your navigation stack consistent. Pushing B onto A can occur with either a segue or `pushViewController:animated:`.

Comment: Yup, that appears to be the solution here.  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.  I just segue from A to B now, and once B is complete it can just popToViewController and we're good

Answer (score 1):

First, I believe you mean "view controller", right?

If that's the case, there are many ways you could navigate from A to B. However, it seems like you're using the NavigationController in an unusual way.

For example, is it necessary to have a segue from the root to B? If not, then maybe you should create a single segue from A to B and, when you're at B, you can use "popToRootViewController" to go back.

Or maybe you could present B modally instead of having a "show"/"push" segue to it. In that case, you would have to go back to A before going to the root.

Anyway, once you're at ViewController B, you can popToRootViewController and you'll get back to your root.

Comment: the popToRootViewController sounds interesting.  I guess I could do 'popToViewController' as well if I wanted to to back multiple items in the stack, but not necessarily back to the root right?

Comment: Yes, you can use popToViewController and specify the viewController that you want to appear at the top of the navigation stack. It's important to notice that the viewController you wanna go to must already be in the navigation stack.