# Unwind UIStoryboardSegue without showing previous view controllers

Tags: ios, uikit, uistoryboardsegue

How can I unwind through multiple view controllers without displaying each one sequentially?
I have 3 view controllers, let's call them A, B, and C.
A uses presentViewController to present B, and B does the same with C. When I use an unwind method from C, first C vanishes, showing B, and then B vanishes, showing A. How can I get it to return to A directly, without ever displaying B?

Comment: I am seeing the exact same behavior with iOS 11 and Xcode 9.3. Segue from A to B, then B to C. Unwinding from C to A shows a brief flash of B.  The reference from @CodeBender does not address this problem. I worked around it by bringing a neutral background view to the foreground in `B.viewDidDisappear()`. This only works, of course, if the neutral view blends in with A's background. See a similar question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26785511/how-to-unwind-through-multiple-views-without-displaying-intermediate-views/26786895.

Answer (score 2):

[How an Unwind Segue Determines its Destination View Controller](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2298/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40013591-CH1-DETDEST)

> When an unwind segue is initiated, it must first locate the nearest
>   view controller in the navigation hierarchy which implements the
>   unwind action specified when the unwind segue was created. This view
>   controller becomes the destination of the unwind segue. If no suitable
>   view controller is found, the unwind segue is aborted.

This link contains information for setting up the unwind segue process as well.

Comment: The link seems to suggest overriding canPerformUnwindSegueAction. I tried that, but it does not change anything. The problem isn't the destination view controller, rather that it shows the in-between view controller while performing the unwind.

Comment: I'm seeing this also. Would appreciate if you or anyone else has found a solution or workaround.