# Custom UIStoryboardSegue to unwind multiple view controllers

Tags: ios, objective-c, uistoryboardsegue

Assume that we have 3 view controllers: `A`, `B`, and `C`. `A` is the root view controller, which has presented `B`, and `B` has in turn presented `C`. How can we perform a custom unwind segue from `C` to `A` that does not reveal `B`?

```
A - B - C
```

A `UIStoryboardSegue` has a reference to its source view controller as well as its destination view controller, but what about the view controllers in between (`B` in our example)? We can perform whatever animations we want on `C`, but I don't see how we can affect `B` in any way.

The goal is simply to dismiss all but the root (`B` and `C`) to the right while having `A` come in from the left, so both source and destination are swiping horizontally next to each other. `B` should not be visible at any point of the animation.

My example dismisses only two views, but I hope to find a solution that would apply to an arbitrary number of views. Furthermore, I am not interested in solving this using a `UINavigationController`. I have tried simply dismissing `B`, which does indeed dismiss `C` as well, but you can still see both `B` and `C` during the animation.

Comment: You can take a look at Unwind Segues. Here is the example [Unwind Segues in iOS Storyboards](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2014/10/25/ios-unwind-segues/).

Comment: The question is about unwind segues.

Comment: So, have you try doing it as in the example?

Comment: The example is just on how to use unwind segues in general. They are not creating any custom animations. I understand how to make an unwind segue, that is not the issue.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26785511/how-to-unwind-through-multiple-views-without-displaying-intermediate-views

Answer (score 0):

You can dissmiss your controller as below :

```
    self.presentingViewController?.presentingViewController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil) // you need to track viewcontroller's stack hierarchy
```

Comment: I can't seem to perform a custom dismiss animation without revealing the middle view during the animation, as stated in the last sentence of the question.

Comment: did you try first ?

Comment: Again, as stated in the question: "I have tried simply dismissing B, which does indeed dismiss C as well, but you can still see both B and C during the animation"

Comment: Are you using a custom UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? If so, could you show me how you perform animations on all dismissing views and not just on the bottom-most one?

Comment: The documentation for dismiss:animated: says "only the top-most view is dismissed in an animated fashion; any intermediate view controllers are simply removed from the stack."